# swift code not working in Xcode 7 (setCategory, AVFormatIDKey,AVAudioRecorder)

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a piece of code that was previously working in Xcode 6 but not now in Xcode 7. I have a picture of it here [errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IdGFb.png)

I'm getting 3 errors about "Cannot assign a value", "Cannot invoke 
initializer", "Cannot invoke Setcategory",

Also, here is the code, any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Best,

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class RecordViewController: UIViewController {

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {


    var baseString : String = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)[0] as String
    self.audioURL = "sound.m4a"
    var pathComponents = [baseString, self.audioURL]
    var audioNSURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPathComponents(pathComponents)
    var session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord, error: nil)

    var recordSettings: [NSObject : AnyObject] = Dictionary()
    recordSettings[AVFormatIDKey] = kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC
    recordSettings[AVSampleRateKey] = 44100.0
    recordSettings[AVNumberOfChannelsKey] = 2

    self.audioRecorder = AVAudioRecorder(URL: audioNSURL, settings: recordSettings, error: nil)
    self.audioRecorder.meteringEnabled = true
    self.audioRecorder.prepareToRecord()

    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}


@IBOutlet weak var recordButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var playButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var saveButton: UIBarButtonItem!

var audioRecorder : AVAudioRecorder
var audioURL = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.playButton.enabled = false
    self.saveButton.enabled = false

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

@IBAction func cancelTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}

@IBAction func saveTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
}

@IBAction func recordTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.playButton.enabled = true
}

@IBAction func playTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
do {
       try session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord)
} catch (_) {

}

var recordSettings: [String : AnyObject] = Dictionary()
recordSettings[AVFormatIDKey] = NSNumber(unsignedInt: kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC)
recordSettings[AVSampleRateKey] = 44100.0
recordSettings[AVNumberOfChannelsKey] = 2

self.audioRecorder = AVAudioRecorder()

do {
      self.audioRecorder = try AVAudioRecorder(URL: audioNSURL!, settings: recordSettings)
} catch (_) {

}
```

Basically, with Swift 2, you need to handle exceptions and type casting little differently.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response Abhinav. I followed as you suggested and the first two errors are gone. For the third one, I'm still getting "Cannot invoke initializer..."

Comment: Can you please attach the screenshot of the error. For me everything looked fine earlier when I responded.

Comment: Thanks a lot Abhinav. Thanks to Abhinav this problem is solved. Also, for the third error, I mistakenly had not followed Abhinav answer completely and I had "var recordSettings: [NSObject : AnyObject] = Dictionary()" instead of "var recordSettings: [String : AnyObject] = Dictionary()". After changing to what Abhinav had suggested previously, code started to work again. My sincere appreciations to you.

Answer (score 0):

i've been trying for a long time to solve this problem ,and below is the solution,hope it could help you,run on Xcode 7.3.1

```
do {
    try session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord)
} catch {
}
//i think most of the problem come from here
var recordSettings = [AVFormatIDKey : NSNumber(unsignedInt: kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC),
                         AVSampleRateKey :  44100 as NSNumber,
                         AVNumberOfChannelsKey : 1 as NSNumber,
                         AVEncoderAudioQualityKey :AVAudioQuality.Low.rawValue as NSNumber
        ]

self.audioRecorder = AVAudioRecorder()

do {
  self.audioRecorder = try AVAudioRecorder(URL: audioNSURL!, settings: recordSettings)
} catch{
}
```